# Postgres Where Value in Json Array of Objects

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I am working in Postgres V11 and have a table with a field (typeid) of int4 type.

I also have JSONB data I am getting from another table and storing into a local variable.

This data looks like

```
{"Types":[{"Category": "a", "TypeID": 26}, {"Category": "a", "TypeID": 27}, {"Category": "b", "TypeID": 28}, {"Category": "c", "TypeID": 30}, {"Category": "d", "TypeID": 29}]}
```

The query I am trying to write is

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE typeid is contained in this json data
```

So, I only want the rows in the table returned if the typeid is listed in the json array.

I have tried different combination of this, but have yet to find something that works.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE typeid @> ANY (jsondata -> 'Types' -> 'TypeID')
```

The jsondata -> 'Types' seems to return just the array, but I can't seem to figure out how to specify I want to compare against the TypeID value in the object.

Postgres keeps returning

ERROR:  op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side

So, I tried returning just the array, but it doesn't know what to compare against.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "storing into a local variable" Local to what?

Comment: This is part of a larger Postgres function, so more specifically the data is stored in a jsonb function variable and does not exist in the same table I am selecting against.  The sample json data is a simplified version of what I am deal with, but the only field I care about for this part is the TypeID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ANY takes a PostgreSQL array, not an JSON array.  Because JSON arrays can have heterogeneous types, they are not trivially convertible to PostgreSQL arrays.  You could create a help function to do this conversion.

```
create function jsonb_to_intarray(jsonb,property text) returns int[] immutable parallel safe language SQL as $$
  select array_agg((x->>$2)::int) from jsonb_array_elements($1) f(x)
$$;
```

And then:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE typeid =ANY (jsonb_to_intarray(jsondata -> 'Types', 'TypeID'));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no single operator that you can use. You will need to unnest the array and test each element:

```
select t.*
from the_table t
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(t.jsondata -> 'Types') as j(element)
              where j.element ? 'TypeID')
```

This would list rows where at least one array element contains `TypeID`.